# arithmetic variables in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to process arithmetic expressions with variables in it. Variables should be left as it is, and the other parts should be calculated. For example,

```
?-result(7*x,R).
R=7*x.

?-result(x+(2*3),R).
R=x+6.
```

How should I do this?

Comment: oh im so sorry about my sloppiness. I just edited it.

Comment: Define rules such as `result(X * Y, R) :- ...` and check whether `X` or `Y` is actually a number (you can use `number(X)` which is true if `X` is a number). Evaluate if they're numbers, process recursively if it's not an atom (*e.g.*, `x` is an atom, but `x + 3` is not). Give that a go and come back with a specific question if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: You also need to explain what you mean by *process*. Do you mean *simplification*? For example, do you expect to take, `3*(x+4) - (x+5)` and get `R = 2*x + 7`? That's well suited for Prolog but not a beginner's program.